# Excel formula to convert minutes to HH:MM format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've found a gazillion examples/demos to convert HH:MM time into a number of minutes, but I have an integer value representing the minutes, and wish to display that number in another cell as HH:MM.

I'm not great with Excel. I've tried numerous things, here's one:

```
=TEXT(INT(O18/60)+MOD(O18,60), "00\:00")
```

Cell O18 has an integer value, such as 517 - I wish to display that number as, basically:
`(517/60) : MOD(517/60)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, using the `TIME` function:

```
=TEXT(TIME(0,O18,0),"hh:mm")
```

Or since there are 1440 minutes per day:

```
=TEXT(O18/1440,"hh:mm")
```

Or just use `=O18/1440` and apply a number format of `hh:mm` to the cell.